# Android take a picture and display it

Tags: android, camera

I have a question,
I am taking picture with a button click, however I want to display it with the same button click in my imageView. But it doesn’t work, because the picture is not yet saved, how can I wait for takePicture to save and then display it?

Comment: if you haven't already, check [Photo Basics @ developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html)

Comment: I did check that however I have custom camera. I can load the photo with another button click but not directly the same as I take photo. Thats the problem.

Comment: Post your code that you have tried